# Вертикальный overflow

Tags: html, css

Делаю табличку, в которой шапка и нумерация строк должны быть зафиксированы и видимы всегда при прокрутке контента, при этом необходимо, чтобы сама табличка динамически подстраивалась под выделенный ей блок, а в шапке и столбце нумерации строк не было скроллинга.

С шапкой проблем нет, родителю ставлю `overflow: auto;`, в дочернем, чтобы спрятать скроллинг `overflow: hidden;` и элемент нормально вписывается в выделенный ей блок, невидимая часть прячется, а вот со столбцом номеров такой фокус не прокатывает. Если не ставим дочернему `overflow: hidden;`, то вроде все нормально, но видим скроллинг (который нужно спрятать), а если выставляем `overflow: hidden`, то родитель по высоте становится равным контенту, весь день не могу победить его.

Пример кода (код прокрутки на javascript убрал, чтобы не загромождать):
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jw23he89/1/)

```
<style type="text/css">
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.lframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.lframe_content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>

<div style="width: 400px; height: 250px;">

<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"><tr><td>
    <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div>
</td><td>
    <table class="lframe"><tr><td>
        <div class="lframe_content" style="overflow: hidden;">
            <table style="position: relative;"><tr>
                <td>000001</td>
                <td>000002</td>
                <td>000003</td>
                <td>000004</td>
                <td>000005</td>
                <td>000006</td>
            </tr></table>
        </div>
    </td></tr></table>
</td></tr><tr><td>
    <table class="lframe"><tr><td>
        <div class="lframe_content">
            <table style="position: relative;">
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>4</td></tr>
                <tr><td>5</td></tr>
                <tr><td>6</td></tr>
                <tr><td>7</td></tr>
                <tr><td>8</td></tr>
                <tr><td>9</td></tr>
                <tr><td>10</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td></tr></table>
</td><td style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    cells
</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Будет работать, если выставить фикс. высоту требуемому блоку с классом `lframe_content`: [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/jw23he89/2/)

Comment: В том то и дело, что хочется динамическую верстку, по горизонтали же она работает нормально. Вообще у меня получилось добиться желаемого эффекта костылем, указав маленькую высоту lframe_content-а, тогда он растягивается по высоте родителя нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Вытаскивай заголовочные строки и столбцы за пределы таблицы при помощи `position:absolute`. Кроме того, таблицу придётся обернуть в 2 дополнительных div'a, у внешнего поставить `position:relative` и паддинги по размеру заголовочных областей. Можно обойтись одним обёрточным div'ом, но тогда придётся прописать *таблице* `display:block`.

Ну и да, всё это получится только если известна ширина и высота выносимых ячеек, *либо* таблица не имеет видимых границ и hover-эффектов.